Incorrect factor in radial wavefunction $R_{2,1}$ of hydrogen atom
First of all, let me state that this isn’t a homework question but rather my personal annoyance. I can provide a proof in the comments if you think otherwise. The general equation for radial wave function is
$$R_{n,l}(r)=\sqrt{\left(\frac{2}{na_0}\right)^3\frac{(n-l-1)!}{2n((n+l)!)^3}} e^{-\frac{r}{na_0}} \left(\frac{2r}{na_0}\right)^l L_{n-l-1}^{2l+1}\left(\frac{2r}{na_0}\right).$$
When I enter $n=2$ and $l=1$ into the equation, I have a factor of $1/\sqrt{(24)(36)}$ instead of $1/\sqrt{24}$. The other factors are correct. I spent a day and still don’t understand why there is such discrepancy between the general formula and functions presented in literature for $n=2,l=1$.

Note: Factor means "multiplier".
Edited Note 2: I want to find that
$$R_{2,1}= \sqrt{\frac{1}{24}} \left(\frac{r}{a_0}\right)e^{-\frac{r}{a_0}}$$
whereas I find
$$R_{2,1}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{(24)(36)}} \left(\frac{r}{a_0}\right)e^{-\frac{r}{a_0}}.$$ Riley Scott has notified me about different definitions of Laguerre Polynomials between authors. The notation that I am aware of is
$$L_n^m=\frac{x^{-\alpha}}{n!} \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}-1\right)^n x^{n+\alpha}.$$

When you say factor, what do you even mean? You should state both what you obtained, and what it should be, so that people can judge.

Factor as in “multiplier”. For example 4 can be written with two factors as (2)(2). I am editing to make this clear. Or should I just call it “multiplier”?

I will do that when I switch to computer in about 15-30 minutes. I wrote the question on mobile when I decided to finally ask it.

The correct factor is factor with which $$\int \text{d}r , r^2 |R_{n, l}(r)|^2 = 1$$

I agree with you @Sancol. but why does the general equation does not satisfy it? That’s what confuses me.

It is not at all clear from your question what you got when you actually tried this.

What is $L^3_0(\dfrac{r}{a_0})$? Are you consider the factor that it enters to radial function?

It is equal to 1. The L stands for Associated Laguerre Polynomials and $L_0^a (x)=1$
For any positive a and x

This is due to differences in definitions of the Laguerre polynomials between authors

Riley Scott Jacob is correct. All of this would have been much easier to catch if you wrote down everything to the details. By not presenting everything together, people trying to help you are lost along with you because nobody can check whether you have used a consistent convention scheme.

I wasn’t aware that there was multiple definitions that was incompatible with one another. Edited my post to reflect it. Thanks @RileyScottJacob
Is it possible that the equation I am using demands a different Laguerre?

Without proper references one can only guess at the answer.

I believe this mismatch has to do with differences between different authors' choices for the Laguerre polynomials.
I was able to find sources which contain the form in your question here and here, as well as in Griffiths.
There is a power of 3 to which the factorial expression is being raised in the denominator. There is no such power in forms from several other sources, which is: $$R_{n,\ell}(r)=\sqrt{\left(\frac{2}{na_0}\right)^3\frac{(n-\ell-1)!}{2n(n+\ell)!}}e^{-\rho/2}\rho^\ell L_{n-\ell-1}^{2\ell+1}(\rho)$$ where $\rho=2r/na_0$. You appear to be using this form's corresponding convention for the Laguerre polynomials.
As a source for the polynomials corresponding to the form you give, Griffiths specifies $L_0^3=6$ (which accounts for the difference you see).

Thank you so much. I had no idea there was different definitions of Laguerre and wasn't able to realise such possibility existed. I can finally understand what was happening. Thank you once again : )
